# Does Q ever appear when an admiral is onboard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q

Q generally always appears with a captain's rank. Does he ever appear when an admiral is aboard?

The one time I am certain of is in "All Good Things," with Riker as Admiral, but that was another timeline created by Q.  In the "real" timeline, does Q ever visit when an admiral is aboard?

Was an admiral at DS9 when Q visited?

Comment: Q appears as a captain because his favorite human is Picard.

Comment: Maybe I remember this wrong, but wasn't there one instance where he tried to command Janeway around? Or was that just based on their "setting" (think it was one of the civil war episodes?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No, he doesn't.

Listed below are the episodes where Q is present (and his presence is known to anyone on the ship, as we can assume that Q always watches the Enterprise ;) ) and whether any reference to an admiral (on-board) appears in the scripts:

- [TNG] Encounter at Farpoint - Admiral McCoy leaves the Enterprise before Q appears, so **NO**.
- [TNG] Hide and Q - the only admiral onboard is Q himself (pretending to be), so I guess it does not count, therefore: **NO**.
- [TNG] Q Who - **NO**
- [TNG] Deja Q - **NO**
- [TNG] Qpid - **NO**
- [TNG] True Q - **NO**
- [TNG] Tapestry - **NO**
- [TNG] All Good Things... - Admiral Riker's case excluded, therefore: **NO**
- [DS9] Q-less - **NO**
- [VOY] Death Wish - **NO**
- [VOY] The Q and the Grey - **NO**
- [VOY] Q2 - **NO**

As far as I remember, in DS9 admirals do not arrive at the station before the Dominion War or its prelude, and in VOY, there are no (real) admirals on board during most of the episodes.

Therefore, the answer to the question is that **Q does not appear aboard USS Enterprise, USS Voyager or Deep Space 9, during any admiral's known stay.**

Comment: Makes me think the admiralty should at some point wondered if Q is Picards imaginary friend.